# What does 'SGDClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit_predict' means?

Tags: python

I  was trying  to build a model based on ML Algorithms for Restaurant Reviews Analysis.
Here is the code

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JSRqFfjftvQcByayerPy2f1XcE1WbS9I?authuser=1#scrollTo=s7mPS0uoSW0U

I have errors in two parts

```
vect = CountVectorizer()
tfidf = TfidfTransformer()
clf = SGDClassifier()
vX = vect.fit_transform(x_train)
tfidfX = tfidf.fit_transform(vX)
predicted = clf.fit_predict(tfidfX)
# Now evaluate all steps on test set
vX = vect.fit_transform(x_test)
```

---

```
AttributeError        Traceback (most recent call last
 <ipython-input-131-1cdb6826a329> in <module>()
  4 vX = vect.fit_transform(x_train)
  5 tfidfX = tfidf.fit_transform(vX)
  6 predicted = clf.fit_predict(tfidfX)
  7 # Now evaluate all steps on test set
  8 vX = vect.fit_transform(x_test)
 AttributeError: 'SGDClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit_predict'

  and 
 pipeline = pipeline([
 ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
 ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
 ])
 predicted = pipeline.fit(x_train).predict(x_train)
 # Now evaluate all steps on test set
 predicted = pipeline.predict(x_test)TypeError                                 
  Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-34-5b0a092ed296> in <module>()
    2 ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    3 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    4 ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
    5 ])
    6 predicted = pipeline.fit(x_train).predict(x_train)

      1 frames
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py in check_task(task)
354 
355     """
356     if task in TASK_ALIASES:
357         task = TASK_ALIASES[task]
358     if task in SUPPORTED_TASKS:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can i fix with the unhashable type?
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Tuple element is not callable means your code has `(...)(...)` where you probably meant `(...),(...)`. Put commas  at the ends of lines 2-4.

Comment: I did like you told me too but its still giving me errors like TypeError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-5b0a092ed296> in <module>()
      2 ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
      3 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
----> 4 ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
      5 ])
      6 predicted = pipeline.fit(x_train).predict(x_train)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'     How can i fix this again?

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. It's unreadable and that means nobody will read it: instead, [edit] your question to include any clarification of what you're asking.

Comment: Okay thank you  I did that. Im new here so im not used to it.